# Why does selectAnnotation not work in this scenario?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am setting up a MapView annotation when my map view appears with the following code, which all seems to be working fine except the selection:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    MapAnnotation *pinpoint = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" andCoordinate:loc];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 1500, 1500);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:true];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:pinpoint];
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:pinpoint animated:true];  //nothing happens!?   
}
```

But if call the same method in this callback, it works fine:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    [mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}
```

What is causing this?  Is this just not the appropriate place to call selectAnnotation?  Do I have to wait until after viewForAnnotation has been called?

Comment: My solution in other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13026353/736384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation view has to have been added before you can select the annotation.

Please see this popular question:

[How to trigger MKAnnotationView's callout view without touching the pin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978897/how-to-trigger-mkannotationviews-callout-view-without-touching-the-pin)