# ios MapKit have annotation description visible on launch and not on tap

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

I am using map on my IOS application. I can see the annotation on my map, and when I tap on that there is the description, which I have set. My question is whether I can have this description visible when map first loads and not make the user tap on the annotation to view it?

is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256875/wanted-how-to-reliably-consistently-select-an-mkmapview-annotation.  Calling selectAnnotation in didAddAnnotationViews should work though you may have to first center the map on the annotation's coordinate just before you add the annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an overlay instead of an annotation