# MKAnnotationView custom button image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, mkannotationview

I am trying to use a custom image on my `MKAnnotationView` when I use the following code I get no image on my annotation. I have checked in debug to ensure the image is being properly loaded into the `UIImage`.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {


    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"String"];
    if(!annotationView) {

        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"String"];
        UIButton *directionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIImage *directionIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IconDirections"];

        [directionButton setImage:directionIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = directionButton;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two main issues:

1. The `frame` of the custom callout button is not set making it essentially invisible.
2. An `MKAnnotationView` is being created but its `image` property (the image of the annotation itself -- not the callout button's) is not set.  This makes the whole annotation invisible.

For issue 1, set the button's frame to some appropriate value.  For example:

```
UIImage *directionIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IconDirections"];
directionButton.frame = 
    CGRectMake(0, 0, directionIcon.size.width, directionIcon.size.height);
```

For issue 2, set the annotation view's `image` (or create an `MKPinAnnotationView` instead):

```
annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeIcon"];
```

Additionally, you should handle view re-use correctly by updating the `annotation` property.
Complete example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{    
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"String"];
    if(!annotationView) {

        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"String"];

        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeIcon"];

        UIButton *directionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIImage *directionIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IconDirections"];
        directionButton.frame = 
            CGRectMake(0, 0, directionIcon.size.width, directionIcon.size.height);

        [directionButton setImage:directionIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = directionButton;
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else {
        //update annotation to current if re-using a view
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }    

    return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the callout to be shown, the annotation must be selected. To do this programmatically, call:

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
```

where `annotation` is the specific `MKAnnotation` for which you want a callout displayed.

You'll almost certainly want to put this in `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views`.

There are a few caveats to consider, so here are two other posts that have some great answers and relevant discussions:

- [How to trigger MKAnnotationView's callout view without touching the pin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978897/how-to-trigger-mkannotationviews-callout-view-without-touching-the-pin)
- [Wanted: How to reliably, consistently select an MKMapView annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256875/wanted-how-to-reliably-consistently-select-an-mkmapview-annotation)