# How to select a map pin programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, dictionary, mkmapview

I am new to Maps Concept.

Please find the attached image once.

[image]

when i click the "pin" i am getting message says "Admire your smile" or any text..... Now i want like... when we select the table view,  i need to raise that message for that pin(with out user interaction for that pin)...

I am using below code for This maps and pins.

```
    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
customLocation.latitude=[casesobjc.latitude_string doubleValue];
        customLocation.longitude=[casesobjc.longitude_string doubleValue];
 MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:casesobjc.locationForMap_string andCoordinate:customLocation];
[mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
}
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>) annotation {
 MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"annotation_ID"];
if (pin == nil) {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"annotation_ID"];
    } else {
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    }
    pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    pin.animatesDrop = YES;
    pin.canShowCallout=YES;
return pin;
}
```

Now i will show all the pins once like below.

[image]

How to do When we click on table view i need to show the title for that pin like how we show when we select a pin?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did u mention the anotation tap view with custom image / custom map pin call out view?

Comment: i did not understand?... i used this code but not works.. i.e.,   customLocation.latitude=appdelegate.appDelegateLatitude;
        customLocation.longitude=appdelegate.appDelegateLongitude;
        MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:casesobjc.locationForMap_string andCoordinate:customLocation];
        [mapView selectAnnotation:newAnnotation animated:YES];  @Spynet

Comment: Just pass the title name when the row is selected and set the title for annotation

Comment: i set the titles.. which method i need to call.   i set the titles for all pins  like this  MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:casesobjc.locationForMap_string andCoordinate:customLocation];  @sugan.s

Comment: what is casesobjec.location and what u get in tableviewDidSelectedRowAtIndexPath @Babul

Comment: I am loading static data (different location names with respective latitude and longitude)...  when i select the table view i get an array with objects that is caseObject. It contains the title, latitude, longitude .  @sugan.s

Comment: by using [mapView selectAnnotation:newAnnotation animated:YES];  this one you can't get your requirement?

Comment: ok....Thank you.....how can i achieve my req.? @Sunny

Comment: try like this [mapView selectAnnotation:[[mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES]; may be it'l help you.

Comment: i write code like this .. customLocation.latitude=appdelegate.appDelegateLatitude;
            customLocation.longitude=appdelegate.appDelegateLongitude;
            MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:casesobjc.locationForMap_string andCoordinate:customLocation];
            [mapView selectAnnotation:newAnnotation animated:YES];  @Sunny

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978897/how-to-trigger-mkannotationviews-callout-view-without-touching-the-pin

Comment: Hi @Babul Have you found a solution to this issue yet? I think I have quite [a similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144466/how-to-select-map-pin-when-tapping-table-row-that-associates-with-it). Could you please share the solution with me? Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

The method that you are looking for is **selectAnnotation:**.

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you have to find the annotation associated with the table row.

Once you find it, you can tell it, to select it by using:

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:foundAnnotation animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think I have quite a similar issue. Could you please help take a look into my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144466/how-to-select-map-pin-when-tapping-table-row-that-associates-with-it) also? I just cannot figure it out especially on how to find the annotation associated with the table row.

Answer (score 7):

The same as the Objective C answer, in your tableview you have a list of annotations. In Swift in the `didSelectRow`:

For Swift 4:

```
// annotations would be the array of annotations - change to your required data sets name
let selectedAnnotation = annotations[indexPath.row]
self.mapView.selectAnnotation(selectedAnnotation, animated: true)
```

Short and simple.